# Hacker Rank Challenge : Find count of substrings which are special palindrome

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, c++14

I am getting timeout for test cases having very large input.

-= [Challenge Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/special-palindrome-again/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=strings) =-

-= [Test case example](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/71637/input02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1535648224&Signature=5SOqMgWSZSFHFbJWvS0gKLfI9JM%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) =-

Code is working fine as can be checked on [ideone](https://ideone.com/hkfRcY). (Note: Here `fout` has been replaced with `cout`.)

> **Problem Statement :**
>
> A string is said to be a special palindromic string if either of two
>   conditions is met:
>
> - All of the characters are the same, e.g. aaa.
> - All characters except the middle one are the same, e.g. aadaa.
>
> A special palindromic
>   substring is any substring of a string which meets one of those
>   criteria. Given a string, determine how many special palindromic
>   substrings can be formed from it.
>
> For example, given the string s = mnonopoo , we have the following special
>   palindromic substrings: {m, n, o, n, o, p, o, o, non, ono, opo, oo}.
>
> **Function Description**
>
> Complete the substrCount function in the editor below. It should
>   return an integer representing the number of special palindromic
>   substrings that can be formed from the given string.
>
> substrCount has the following parameter(s):
>
> - n: an integer, the length of string s
> - s: a string
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains an integer, n , the length of s.  The second line
>   contains the string .
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1 ≤ n ≤ 10^6
>
> Each character of the string is a lowercase alphabet, ascii[a-z].
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print a single line containing the count of total special palindromic
>   substrings.
>
> **Sample Input 0**
>
> ```
> 5 
> asasd
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 0**
>
> ```
> 7
> ```
>
> **Explanation 0**
>
> The special palindromic substrings of s = asasd are {a, s, a, s, d, asa, sas}.
>
> **Sample Input 1**
>
> ```
> 7 
> abcbaba
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 1**
>
> ```
> 10
> ```
>
> **Explanation 1**
>
> The special palindromic substrings of s = abcbaba are {a, b, c, b, a, b, a, bcb, bab, aba}.
>
> **Sample Input 2**
>
> ```
> 4 
> aaaa
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 2**
>
> ```
> 10
> ```
>
> **Explanation 2**
>
> The special palindromic substrings of s = aaaa are {a, a, a, a, aa, aa, aa, aaa, aaa, aaaa}.

**Code:**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

// Complete the substrCount function below.
long substrCount(int n, string s) {

    long int length_sub = 2;
    long int count = n;
    while(length_sub <= n){
        for(long int i = 0; i <= n - length_sub ; i++){
            string sub = s.substr(i, length_sub);
            //cout << sub << " ";
            string rev_sub(sub);
            reverse(rev_sub.begin(), rev_sub.end());
            //cout << rev_sub;;
            char c = sub[0];
            int flag = 0;
            for(long int j = 0; j < sub.length() / 2; j++){
                if(sub[j] != c || rev_sub[j] != c){
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag == 0){
                //cout << " - Special\n";
                count++;
            }
            // else{
            //     cout << "\n";
            // }
        }
        length_sub++;
    }
    return count;

}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    string s;
    getline(cin, s);

    long result = substrCount(n, s);

    fout << result << "\n";

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure it belongs here... codereview isn't about improving algorithms as far as I know. That said, a hint: don't create an endless stream of substrings when you can use iterators instead

Comment: @papagaga Improving algorithms is absolutely part of Code Review. That's what many of the [tag:algorithm] and [tag:time-limit-exceeded] questions are about.

Comment: @papagaga Algorithms can always be improved—often immensely. As long as the code posted meets the requirements of the site, it's on-topic. All parts are considered reviewable, even if its a question that is masquerading as a code review for some other nefarious purpose.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast I did not i just removed all commented code lines which i used for debugging

Comment: @Phoenix Which was pointed out in an answer. So if you remove them, that part of the answer makes no sense. That's answer invalidation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
```

is given by the submission template from HackerRank (so it is not your fault),
but note that both lines are generally considered as bad practice.
See for example

- [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/1187415)
- [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1187415)

on Stack Overflow.

With respect to your

```
long substrCount(int n, string s)
```

function:

- The outer `while` loop could be made a `for` loop as well – why should it
  be different from the inner `for(long int ...)` loop?
- The proper data type for `string` lengths and indices is `string::size_type`
  aka `size_t`.

One step to increase the efficiency would be to avoid the creation (and reversal)
of the additional strings `sub` and `rev_sub`. All tests can be done directly on
the original string `s`. As an example,

```
if (sub[j] != c || rev_sub[j] != c)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (s[i + j] != c || s[i + length_sub - 1 - j] != c)
```

Your method checks all \$ n (n-1)/2 \$ substrings of length 2 or more if 
it is a “special palindromic string.”. The following approach seems more
efficient to me:

- The number of substrings with all identical characters (e.g. "aaa")
  can be determined with a single traversal of the string. All sequences
  of \$ k \$ contiguous identical characters contain \$ k(k+1)/2 \$
  substrings with identical characters.
- To determine the number of substrings where characters except the middle one
  are the same (e.g. "aadaa") traverse the string, and check for each character
  (e.g. "d") how many identical characters exist to the left and to the right
  of this character.

*Example:* The string "mnonopoo" has the following sequences of contiguous 
identical characters

```
m n o n o p oo
```

which gives a total

```
1+1+1+1+1+1+3 = 9
```

substrings with all identical characters. The number of substrings where
all characters except the middle one are the same around each character are

```
m n o n o p o o
0+0+1+1+0+1+0+0 = 3
```

Answer (score 6):

First, the things which are bad about the form:

1. `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is non-standard and probably far too much.
2. `using namespace std;` is evil because `std` is not designed to be imported wholesale, making conflicts and silent changes, now and in future, likely.
3. `long substrCount(int n, string s)` is also a bad idea. `n` duplicates `s.size()` but with the wrong type (it should be `string::size_type`).
4. The code assumes that input won't fail. That's generally wrong.
5. `return 0;` is implicit for `main()`.

Now, about your code:

6. All your comments are just a distraction, as they contain cryptic code-fragments. Clean them up.
7. If you want to create a reverse of a range, just initialize the copy with reverse-iterators instead of copying and then reversing. `rbegin()` and `rend()` are your friends.
8. If you want to know whether a range is all copies of the same element except the middle, take a look at [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count):

   ```
   bool my_palindrome = range[range.size() / 2] != range[0]
       && std::count(range.begin(), range.end(), range[0]) == range.size() - 1;
   ```

   Making copies, reversing, and then comparing is just superfluous additional work.
9. Fixing all those small things might lead to a significant speed-up, but it doesn't improve the order of your algorithm which is \$O(n^2)\$.

   For that, move to a different algorithm:

   1. Start with zero.
   2. Find runs of identical characters.
   3. Add the number of substrings for the run, which is \$k * (k + 1) / 2\$.
   4. If the run has length one, and the bordering runs consist of identical characters, add the length of the smaller one.

   That's \$O(n)\$, even single-pass.

Improved version of your function (using C++17 [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) as the parameter to avoid *any* copies, even in the caller, whether he has a `std::string` or not):

```
long substrCount(std::string_view s) noexcept {
    char c[3] = {};
    long n[3] = {};
    long r = 0;
    for (auto curr = begin(s), last = end(s), pos = begin(s); curr != last; curr = pos) {
        pos = std::find_if(curr + 1, last, [=](char c){ return c != *curr; });
        std::tie(n[2], n[1], n[0]) = std::make_tuple(n[1], n[0], pos - curr);
        std::tie(c[2], c[1], c[0]) = std::make_tuple(c[1], c[0], *curr);
        r += *n * (*n + 1) / 2;
        if (n[1] == 1 && c[0] == c[2])
            r += std::min(n[0], n[2]);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: @Deduplicator why did you change the code ?

Comment: The changed code dispenses with the lambda I needed earlier to avoid duplication, and it's shorter by 7 of 25 lines. Unfortunately [`boost::find_not`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/the_boost_algorithm_library/Misc/find_not.html) never made it into the standard, or it would be even better. And I didn't want to include part of boost here just for that.